# Loops and using Sentinel to exit program

Tags: java

Is there a way that I can make case 'x' inside the switch to terminate the program without continuing the loop and printing "Is this customer's order complete? (Y/N)" before terminating.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;

public class YoshisLiqourMart {
  public static void main (String [] args){

//Variables

    //CONSTANTS
    final double GSTTAX = 0.05;
    final double SMALLDEPOSIT = 0.10;
    final double LARGEDEPOSIT = 0.25;

    //PRICE
    double wine_Price = 11.99;
    double beer6_Price = 15.99;
    double beer12_Price = 24.99;
    double beer24_Price = 39.99;
    double spirits750_Price = 25.99;
    double spirits1000_Price = 35.99;

    //SELECTION
    char selection = 0 ;
    char completeOrder = 'Y';
    char quitProgram = 'X';


    //WINE
    int winePurchase;
    double wineDeposit =0.10;
    double wineTotal;
    double wineGST;

    //BEER
    int beerSelection;

    //Beer 6 Pack
    int beer6Purchase;
    double beer6Deposit = 0.60;
    double beer6Total;
    double beer6GST;

    //Beer 12 Pack
    int beer12Purchase;
    double beer12Deposit =1.20 ;
    double beer12Total;
    double beer12GST;

    //Beer 
    int beer24Purchase;
    double beer24Deposit = 2.40;
    double beer24Total;
    double beer24GST;


    //SPIRITS
    int spiritsSelection;

    //Spirits 750 mL
    int spirits750Purchase;
    double spirits750Deposit = .10;
    double spirits750Total;
    double spirits750GST;

    //Spirits 1000 mL 
    int spirits1000Purchase;
    double spirits1000Deposit = .25;
    double spirits1000Total;
    double spirits1000GST;

    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("*** Welcome to Yoshi's Liquor Mart *** ");
    System.out.println("Today's date is:" );
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

    //OPTIONS
    String options ="\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"+
      "\n|      Item |  Quantity |   Price |"+
      "\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"+
      "\n|      Wine |    bottle |  $11.99 |"+
      "\n|      Beer |    6 pack |  $15.99 |"+
      "\n|      Beer |   12 pack |  $24.99 |"+
      "\n|      Beer |   24 pack |  $39.99 |"+
      "\n|   Spirits |    750 mL |  $25.99 |"+
      "\n|   Spirits |   1000 mL |  $35.99 |"+
      "\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++";



    //Prompts
    Scanner yoshisliquormart = new Scanner (System.in);

    do{
      System.out.print(options);
      System.out.print("\nWhat is the item being purchased?\nW for Wine, B for Beer and S for Spirits, or X to quit:");
      selection = yoshisliquormart.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

      switch (selection){

        case'X':
          System.out.print("Thank you.");
          quitProgram++;
          break;

        //Wine  
        case'W':

          System.out.print("How many bottles of wine is being purchase?");
          winePurchase = yoshisliquormart.nextInt();

          //CALCULATION
          wineTotal =(winePurchase * (wine_Price+wineDeposit));
          wineGST = (wineTotal *GSTTAX);

          System.out.printf("The cost of " +winePurchase + " x wine (including GST and deposit) is :%.2f",(wineTotal+wineGST));

          break;

          //Beer
        case 'B':
          System.out.print("What is the size of the beer pack 6,12, or 24?");
          beerSelection =yoshisliquormart.nextInt();


          if (beerSelection == 6){
            System.out.print("How many 6 pack of beer is being purchased?");
            beer6Purchase = yoshisliquormart.nextInt();

            //CALCULATION
            beer6Total = (beer6Purchase * (beer6_Price+beer6Deposit));
            beer6GST = (beer6Total *GSTTAX);

            System.out.printf("The cost of "+ beer6Purchase +" x 6  pack of beer (including GST & deposit)is :%.2f",(beer6Total+beer6GST));
          }

          if (beerSelection ==12){
            System.out.print("How many 12 pack of beer is being purchased?");
            beer12Purchase= yoshisliquormart.nextInt();

            beer12Total = (beer12Purchase * (beer12_Price+beer12Deposit));
            beer12GST = (beer12Total *GSTTAX);

            System.out.printf("The cost of "+ beer12Purchase +" x 12 pack of beer (including GST & deposit)is :%.2f",(beer12Total+beer12GST));
          }

          if (beerSelection == 24){
            System.out.print("How many 24 pack of beer is being purchased?");
            beer24Purchase = yoshisliquormart.nextInt();

            beer24Total = (beer24Purchase * (beer24_Price+beer24Deposit));
            beer24GST = (beer24Total *GSTTAX);

            System.out.printf("The cost of "+ beer24Purchase +" x 24 pack of beer (including GST & deposit)is :%.2f",(beer24Total+beer24GST));
          }

          break;

          //Spirits
        case 'S':

          System.out.print("What size bottle of spirits (in mL) 750 or 1000?");
          spiritsSelection = yoshisliquormart.nextInt();

          if (spiritsSelection ==750){
            System.out.print("How many bottles of 750 mL spirits is being purchased?");
            spirits750Purchase = yoshisliquormart.nextInt();

            //CALCULATION
            spirits750Total = (spirits750Purchase * (spirits750_Price+spirits750Deposit));
            spirits750GST = (spirits750Total *GSTTAX);

            System.out.printf("The cost of "+spirits750Purchase + " x 1000 mL spirits (including GST & deposit):%.2f",(spirits750Total+spirits750GST));

          }

          if (spiritsSelection ==1000){
            System.out.print("How many bottles of 1000 mL spirits is being purchased?");
            spirits1000Purchase = yoshisliquormart.nextInt();

            //Calculation
            spirits1000Total = (spirits1000Purchase * (spirits1000_Price+spirits1000Deposit));
            spirits1000GST = (spirits1000Total *GSTTAX);

            System.out.printf("The cost of "+spirits1000Purchase + " x 1000 mL spirits (including GST & deposit):%.2f",(spirits1000Total+spirits1000GST));

          }
          break;   
      }

      System.out.print("\nIs this customer's order complete? (Y/N)");
      completeOrder = yoshisliquormart.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

      if (completeOrder == 'Y'){
        System.out.printf("The total for this customer is:");
      }
    }while (completeOrder == 'N');


  }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is basically that you have **way** to many code in that one poor method. That alone makes it **hard** for others to read your code and suggest simple improvements. Having ifs in a switch in a loop simply makes it super-hard for human beings to understand what is going on. So, the problem you should focus on is: how can I write my code so that it is easier to read? (and there you would start by creating a lot of smaller helper methods that **together** provide the functionality you need).

Comment: thank you ill try to make it easier to read i just started learning  java. I'll work on it right away.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a boolean in the case then check for it after the switch case.

Ex.
`boolean caseX = false;`
...

```
case'X':
    System.out.print("Thank you.");
    quitProgram++;
    caseX = true;
    break;
```

...

```
if (caseX) break;
System.out.print("\nIs this customer's order complete? (Y/N)");
completeOrder = yoshisliquormart.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
```

Your code seems very overcrowded though. If you clean it up a bit and break it into separate methods a cleaner solution might reveal itself.

Answer (score 0):

If this program is only for yourself and "good programming" isn't so important you could use

```
System.exit(0);
```

that terminates the process and returns the status value 0 (normally the status value isn't important for small projects)

Normally one would use booleans and if-blocks, but since your code is already hard to read I wouldn't suggest it.

The best way would be to order your code (create some small methods instead of this one super long method) and then use the second method (boolean value + if-block)